# Incorrect ModifiedCount and MatchedCount using mongodb/mongo-go-driver and Azure CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, go, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to write a simple CRUD test application using [mongodb/mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) (v1.2.1) which connects to an Azure CosmosDB instance (v3.6). Consider the following code excerpts.

#### Stripped down `Update` function from `Client` struct which is omitted for brevity

```
func (c *Client) Update(ctx context.Context, filter, update bson.M) error {    
    res, err := c.collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update, options.Update())
    if err != nil {
        return Error{ErrFunctional, "failed to update document", err}
    }

    if res.MatchedCount != 1 {
        return Error{
            Code: ErrNotFound,
            msg:  "document not found",
        }
    }

    if res.ModifiedCount != 1 {
        return Error{
            Code: ErrNotUpdated,
            msg:  "document not updated",
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

#### Runner code looks like this

```
type doc struct {
    count int
}

id, err := dbClient.Insert(context.TODO(), doc{1})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("insert failed: %v", err))
}

err = dbClient.Update(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": id}, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"count": 2}})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("update failed: %v", err))
}

err = dbClient.Delete(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": id})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("delete failed: %v", err))
}
```

As you can see in the code, I am trying to accomplish the following steps:

1. Insert a record `{"count": 1}` (This works correctly and document is inserted)
2. Update the insert record to `{"count": 2}` (Fails due to no document found error)
3. Delete the record (Code never reaches here)

The program fails at the 2nd step. I inspected the result returned by the driver and both `MatchedCount` and `ModifiedCount` are always 0. However the database ***was*** updated with correct data. Weird, right? Now interestingly, if I execute the same steps using MongoDB shell (CLI, Installed using brew) then the steps finish without any problems.

I have tried all variations of the filters and update statements to make it work but to no avail. I have a feeling that it has to do with the Golang driver. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Kindly feel free to ask for more information and I will gladly edit the question to provide it.

Comment: Note that CosmosDB is a simulated MongoDB made by Microsoft so it's not 100% compatible with MongoDB go driver. Try using the same code in a real MongoDB server and see if it still fails.

Comment: I failed to mention that this code indeed works with a real MongoDB server. I know CosmosDB MongoDB API is just a simulation but it should be compatible with the official driver :/

Comment: @jfarleyx by "library" you mean the go driver? If the same code works with a real MongoDB server then the bug is in CosmosDB, not the other way around. Also upsert:true is _never_ set by default by any official MongoDB driver, since the implication is enormously bad.

Comment: @jfarleyx if you try to test your code against a real MongoDB server and it does the right things, then you'd know for sure that the bug lies in CosmosDB :)

Comment: @kevinadi disregard my comment, I've deleted it. I did experience the same issue as OP using the collection.replaceone method, but I misread the documentation regarding upsert: true. As you mention, that's not the cause. Perhaps it's some issue with CosmosDB.

Comment: @kevinadi Agreed regarding testing. i just haven't had time to set up a MongoDB to test against and the project at the time required me to use CosmosDB via Golang. It's been a couple months since I completed that project. :)

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microsoft. I was hoping someone ran into this issue before but it seems like it could be environment or driver specific.

Comment: @Nektie I went back to the project where I used the mongo library with Cosmos and confirmed that when I execute Collection.ReplaceOne() it does indeed replace the document, but the matchedcount, modifiedcount, upsertedcount are all 0 and upsertedid is nil. Seems like a bug. Thanks for opening a ticket with MS.

Comment: @jfarleyx Thanks for confirming. Will use all this information in the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a silly mistake in the connection string. For some reason I was using this format.

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@<app>.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&retrywrites=false"`

Changed to this format and everything works now.

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@<app>.mongo.cosmos.azure:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&retrywrites=false"`

SMH.